# Python Regular expressions to return line starting with specific string

Tags: python, regex

i have this file (output.txt)

```
Username:traider

domain:domain.net

 
TECH-1366


Username:traider1

domain:domain.net

 
TECH-1367
```

I can get values after Username and domain

```
 traider,domain.net
 traider1,domain.net
```

but don't know how to get TECH-XXX

desired output:

```
traider,domain.net,TECH-1366
traider1,domain.net,TECH-1367
```

Code:

```
with open ("output.txt", "r") as myfile:
  data=myfile.read()

people = re.findall(r'\bUsername:(\S+)\s+domain:(\S+)\s', data)

for personinfo in people:
    print(','.join(personinfo))
```

I can return only [TECH] but it's incomplete and has brackets

```
tech =  re.findall(r'TECH-*', data)
```

Comment: Just finish your current pattern, [`\bUsername:(\S+)\s+domain:(\S+)\s+(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/WM2kF7/1)

Comment: Tried it yet? Is it working? Or should there be an explicit check for `TECH-\d+`? Then replace `.+` above with this.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\bUsername:(\S+)\s+domain:(\S+)\s+(TECH-\d+)', data)` and got nothing need match for line starting with TECH

Comment: See http://rextester.com/AGF36233. What do you mean by *got nothing need match for line starting with TECH*?

Comment: i mean i got empty file, but when add new line:`tech = re.findall('TECH-\d+',data) and print it then got 
traider,domain.net
['TECH-1366']` (in new line with brackets)

Comment: Do not add anything. Just update the regex in your current code. `people = re.findall(r'\bUsername:(\S+)\s+domain:(\S+)\s+(TECH-\d+)', data)`

Comment: just did it and again empty file

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
people = re.findall(r'\bUsername:(\S+)\s+domain:(\S+).*(TECH-\d+)', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this, you can use the built-in [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and then e.g. a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)  to "bundle" your data:

```
txt="""Username:traider

domain:domain.net


TECH-1366


Username:traider1

domain:domain.net


TECH-1367"""

l = txt.split()

#udt = [ l[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(l), 3)]
# equivalent to list-comprehension above
udt = []
for i in range(0, len(l), 3):
    udt.append( l[i:i + 3] )

print(udt)
```

prints

```
[['Username:traider', 'domain:domain.net', 'TECH-1366'], ['Username:traider1', 'domain:domain.net', 'TECH-1367']]
```

---

To print that as desired:

```
for e in udt:
    print(",".join(map(lambda f:f.split(":")[-1], e)))
```

prints

```
traider,domain.net,TECH-1366
traider1,domain.net,TECH-1367
```

and combined

```
d = [e.split(":")[-1] for e in txt.split()]
for i in range(0, len(d), 3):
    print( ",".join(d[i:i+3]) )
```

Comment: It won't work if the input can contain blocks of text without `TECH-\d+` pattern at its end.

Comment: @Wiktor It won't work for a lot of cases, but that one is not part of the question, nor the sample data...

Comment: only get TECH-1366/67

Comment: @Milister Can you be more specific? And please also provide proper sample data. Please see [mcve] and [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49804996/edit).

Comment: `[[u'TECH-1366']] [[u'TECH-1367']]` is all what i got, i posted sample file in question

Comment: You have not posted a file, just a bit of text - with that, it works as I've demonstrated for you. Have you tried my code? If that does not work for you, you may want to post more details about your Python etc. If it does work (as I suspect) the problem may be with your actual file (or how it's read). You could upload it somewhere and post a link ...

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by splitting the text into items, further splitting to obtain the useful text within each item, followed by some simple conditional formatting:

```
txt="""Username:traider

domain:domain.net


TECH-1366


Username:traider1

domain:domain.net


TECH-1367"""

out = ''
for item in txt.split():
    desired_value = item.split(':')[-1]
    out += desired_value
    if ':' in desired_value:
        out += ','           
    else:
        out += '\n'
```

Or using comprehension:

```
''.join('%s,' % item.split(':')[-1] if ':' in item else '%s\n' % item for item in txt.split())
```

Output:

```
traider,domain.net,TECH-1366
traider1,domain.net,TECH-1367
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found why nothing above worked: it's because of  `^M` i had in file 
It's visible only when open it in vim, when open it using cat it's not visible,once removed it with

```
sys.stdout = open('out.txt','wt')
with open ("output.txt", "r") as myfile:
  data=myfile.read()
print data.replace('\r','')
```

and using @Wiktor Stribiżew code:

```
people = re.findall(r'\bUsername:(\S+)\s+domain:(\S+)\s+First Name:(\S+)\s+Last Name:(\S+)\s+(TECH-\d+)', data)
```

i got desired results, thanks everyone !!